# How to show a custom view help box near the clicked view.

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-custom-view

How to achieve this in android.https://www.google.com/design/spec/motion/choreography.html#choreography-creation This menu appears from the touch point, tying the element to the point of touch.

```
Error message in edittext comes in the bottom of the view
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PopupWindow and then use popupWindow.showAsDropDown(theView).

**Edit:**
Here is an example from my code:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) TimeCheckActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timecheck_popup,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 320, 160, true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    radioButton[1].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(times.size()>1) {
                popupText.setText(times.get(1).toString());
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown((View) radioButton[1]);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I also have xml layout which has Textview ("popupText").

Comment: Hey the popup windows in not padding from the RIGHT|END .Can you help me?MINIMUM API Level 16